# Preserving BeautifulSoup selection order

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If I have a simple document like:

```
<p> hi </p>
<q> hello </q>
<p> bye </p>
<q> try </q>
<p> why </p>
```

And I store it in a BeautifulSoup object called `doc`, calling:

```
> doc.select('p, q')
[<p> hi </p>, <p> bye </p>, <p> why </p>, <q> hello </q>, <q> try </q>]
```

**Is it possible to get these elements in the correct order**? I would like to number these tags so that "hi" gets 1, "hello" gets 2 and so on... This is a minimal example, but in practice I will have to select by class, id and tag name.

Comment: If order matters you will need to walk through the tree and append each element to a list as you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use your own custom finding functions if the builtin methods don't suit your use case.

```
def my_tag(tag):
    if tag.name in ('p', 'q'):
        return True

soup.find_all(my_tag)
```

The result would be

```
 [<p> hi </p>, <q> hello </q>, <p> bye </p>, <q> try </q>, <p> why </p>]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `soup.findAll(['p','q'])`:

```
[<p> hi </p>, <q> hello </q>, <p> bye </p>, <q> try </q>, <p> why </p>]
```

Comment: find can't do classes by default though can it?